# Azure IoTEdge modules fail to connect to IoTHub when using windows containers on windows server

Tags: windows, azure, containers, azure-iot-edge, moby

We are using Azure IotEdge with **Linux containers deployed on an Ubuntu server**. We are *successfully* running a few modules that gather, process and send data to the IoT Hub.

Now, what we want is to deploy another IoTEdge run-time with **windows containers on a windows server**, because we are so forced by requirements. For the purposes of bootstrapping the new environment we just decided to get one of our existing and working modules and deploy it as a windows container on the new run-time. The IoTEdge run-time seems to be running fine, it reports run-time status to the IoTHub, it responds to deployment changes.

- the development machine that builds the images is on a Windows 10 1809 build 17763.194
- the server machine where IoTEdge is running is on the same Windows 10 1809 build 17763.194
- IoTEdge run-time is using the MOBY container engine
- moby_runtime network is set to 'nat' (default)
- IoTEdge module with installed NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client 1.18.1
- the final image of the IoTEdge module for windows container is built from `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime-nanoserver-1809`

What we came across is quite weird. The module client is being successfully initialized:

```
AmqpTransportSettings amqpSetting = new AmqpTransportSettings(TransportType.Amqp_Tcp_Only);
ITransportSettings[] settings = { amqpSetting };

IoTHubModuleClient = await ModuleClient.CreateFromEnvironmentAsync(settings).ConfigureAwait(false);
await IoTHubModuleClient.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Nevertheless, the module is not being able to fetch its Twin from IoTHub, which results in a timeout after **4 minutes (!?)**:

```
await IoTHubModuleClient.GetTwinAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Here are the relevant logs:

```
2019-Feb-13T13:54:53.57620Z |       INFO | Initializing module twin
2019-Feb-13T13:58:53.61382Z |      ERROR | FetchModuleTwin failed for IoT Edge module: 
System.TimeoutException: Operation timeout expired.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.InternalClient.<>c.<ApplyTimeoutTwin>b__64_2(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at IoTEdge.ModuleBase.FetchModuleTwin() in C:\src\IoTEdge-ModuleBase\modulebase.cs:line 30
```

If we change the `moby_runtime` network to 'azure-iot-edge', then the result is the same, but in addition the edgeHub module fails to connect, also.

If we update the IoTEdge module installed NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client from 1.18.1 to 1.19.0 (latest stable currently), the results are no better, but the error is `NullReferenceException`, instead of a timeout.

When debugging the same module, everything works fine.
When deploying in a Linux container on Ubuntu server, again everything works fine.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Please open an issue at github.com/azure/iotedge/issues. The issue template there has instructions on how to include logs that will help in debugging. In the issue, also indicate if you can repro the behavior with simple temp sensor module mentioned in the QuickStart docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! We set the log level to 'debug', but it didn't help. We tested the SimulatedTempSensor. According to its logs everything worked without errors. Even though it reads its twin. We didn't find any differences that could cause this behavior. Both modules use TransportType.Amqp_Tcp_Only. At the end, to our greatest surprise we found that our company firewalls had blocked the entire communication on port 5671. So the question remains, why there was a 4 minute timeout only on that one specific line of code...

Comment: Actually, there were some sporadic connection errors in the logs of module $edgeHub, but because we switched a few times the network type, we didn't suspect the firewall restrictions from the beginning.